# Suspend button only shows screensaver, Not suspending

Tags: suspend, xfce

Running Ubuntu 12.04 with xfce desktop.

When I do a suspend my monitor fades to black, prints some information to a console, and then shows the screensaver. It does not suspend.

This happens when I choose Suspend from my Panel widget, or when I run "xfce4-session-logout --suspend"

What are the next steps to diagnose this? 
Any ideas what might be broken?

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo pm-suspend`?

Comment: @January when I run this my system pauses for about .5 seconds and then the desktop reappears.
<br/>
When I run "sudo xfce4-session-logout --suspend" I receive the error message in a dialog box:  Failed to receive a reply from the session manager. The name org.xfce.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files.

Comment: Nevermind what xfce4 says; the pm-suspend doesn't run correctly. Run it again, then type `dmesg` and post the output.

Comment: Output is here: http://pastebin.com/aTNxXtGq

Comment: OK, we are getting nearer. Please post also /var/log/pm_suspend.log. Also, is this a Lenovo laptop?

Comment: pm_suspend.log is here: http://pastebin.com/Je30QmGs

Laptop is a Dell Latitude E6430, purchased new last week.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5846/discussion-between-january-and-hamlet-darcy)